# URLProtocol doesn't get initialized

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsurlrequest, nsurlprotocol

I am implementing an URLProtocol in an app.

```
import Cocoa

class MyURLProtocol: URLProtocol {

    override init(request: URLRequest, cachedResponse: CachedURLResponse?, client: URLProtocolClient?) {
        super.init(request: request, cachedResponse: cachedResponse, client: client)
    }

    override class func canInit(with request: URLRequest) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override class func canonicalRequest(for request: URLRequest) -> URLRequest {
        return request
    }

    override func startLoading() {
        print("loading")
    }
}
```

Although `canInit(with request: URLRequest)` always returns true, neither `init(…)` nor `canonicalRequest(…)` nor `startLoading()` get called.

`URLProtocol.registerClass` for `MyURLProtocol` is called in `willFinishLaunching` in the `AppDelegate`

I don't know what to do. Yesterday, day code called at least the functions.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using `URLSession`? `URLSession` bypasses the normal protocol registration and instead has you explicitly configure the protocols in the `URLSessionConfiguration`. See [`URLSessionConfiguration.protocolClasses`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411050-protocolclasses).

Comment: No. I am only loading an URLRequest in a WKWebView.

Comment: I need to handle differnt url schemes in my app

Comment: I also implement the WKNavigationDelegate and func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) gets called with an unsupported url error.

Comment: `WKWebView` is an out-of-process webview. It's impossible to have `WKWebView` use your `URLProtocol` subclass because it's running in the wrong process. If you want to use `URLProtocol` with web views, you need to use the old in-process `UIWebView` class instead.

Comment: Huh, it turns out that iOS 11 actually adds a new API that might do what you want. `WKWebViewConfiguration` has a new method `setURLSchemeHandler(_:forURLScheme:)` and some related protocols to allow you to implement custom schemes across the process boundary. This still isn't `URLProtocol` but it should do effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'am working on a macOS app and not an iOS one, but it has fixed the problem when I was changing from WKWebView to WebView.

Thanks to [Kevin Ballard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582/kevin-ballard) on his comment.

Comment: The iOS 11 API is also present in macOS 10.13 (which came out today).